# Custom Object List - Linq Filtering Similar to SQL 'Like' clause

Tags: c#, .net, list

I am using a datatable which works great however I have decided to convert this to a custom object list to preserve some system resources.

In my Custlist I have objects with postcodes:

B1 7NY,
B2 8JK,
B1 XLS,
B9 2BY,

BW7 1NJ,
BF9 3NJ,
BJ4 2NP,
BW8 5DO,

Now in my Listbox the user can select:
B,
BW,
BF,
BJ,

So I need a query that when the user selects 'B' in the listbox, I want to remove all of the B1-B9 postcodes as above.

If the user selects 'BW' I want to remove all of the BW postcodes.

```
customerList.Where(c => c.Postcode.StartsWith(postcodeID.ToString()));
```

This would work fine for when postcode id = BL but what about when the postcode 2nd char is numeric. B1-B9. How do I select all objects where postcode is like b1-b9?

```
   if (char.IsDigit(postcodeID.ToString()[1]))
   {
       CustList.RemoveAll(c => c.Postcode[0] == postcodeID[0] &&
                                                    char.IsDigit(c.Postcode[1]));
   }
   else
   {
       CustList.RemoveAll(c => c.Postcode.StartsWith(postcodeID.ToString()));
   }
```

Comment: StartsWith should be fine for the first x chars.

Comment: Ok great, I guess what I am asking is how do I include an OR. I.e starts with B1 or B2 or B3?

Comment: @codemonkey but it will return BL in all cases.

Comment: @user4316519 you don't wanna include B1,B2 if the second char is not digit, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if the 2nd char is not numeric i just want to query all custom objects where postcode = postcodeid which would be BL in this case. However if the 2nd char is numeric then I want to query all objects where postcode = postcode id which in this case would be just 'B' which I need to query B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9 as multiple postcodes belong to the B area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the second `char` is a *digit* and construct the query based on that:

```
if(char.IsDigit(postcodeID.ToString()[1]))
{
    query = customerList.Where(c => c.Postcode[0] == 'B' &&
                                    char.IsDigit(c.Postcode[1]));
}
else 
{
    query = customerList.Where(c => c.Postcode.StartsWith("BL"));
}
```

Comment: what I need is a query to select any object that starts with B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9. and a query to select any object that starts with BL. So if postcodeid = 1 char, the first query would need to be 'Select * where postcode = postcodeid+1 or postcode = postcodeid+2 and so on. However if postcodeid = 2chars then it would need to be 'Select * where postcode =postcodeid. How do I do this on the list

Comment: many thanks for your help. Can you take a look at my edit to the original post please. Hopefully makes much more sense. thank you